# Checkout Progress Bar disappears after first step

Tags: checkout

I'm having a problem after updating my magento to 1.9.
When I go to checkout ( one page checkout ) the Checkout Progress Bar is there... but when I click continue it goes to the next steps and the Checkout Progress Bar disappears after a few seconds.

I think it's a problem in the opcheckout.js but I'm kinda newbie in that stuff.

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Can you verify that it works with an unmodified theme in place?

Comment: The default theme are getting the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the opcheckout_rwd.js file in your theme is present for that version of Magento.  It could be that an older theme has placed an older version of the file.

Also check the parent theme of the current one just to be sure!

Definitely sounds like a javascript / theme issue to me.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be common issue

1. Checkout Progress Panel is missing or empty.

Fix – You need to compare your checkout.xml file from 1.7 theme and 1.9 base default, we compared below 2 files and there were few blocks missing in theme checkout file. Again this will depend on case by base. Refer to this link , many of us have faced similar issue and you will get your solution

app\design\frontend\default\yourtheme\layout\checkout.xml

app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\checkout.xml

Below is the article which list all the issues and its solution after magento migration.

http://www.siddharthvaghasia.com/2015/01/24/magento-migration/

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you have the [Bürgel credit rating test](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/burgel-bonitatsprufung-beim-checkout.html) installed in version 13.11.06. They did not adapt their JavaScript to the current Magento version 1.9. If you disable the module `Netresearch_Scoring`, it probably works again. I already wrote a mail to Netresearch and will update my answer as soon as I get a response.

**Update**

Bürgel has updated the Scoring extension for us, but has not uploaded a fixed extension to Magento Connect yet. Therefore, here is a patch file:

```
From 5d18418e2a9f23780e6d0f31e50e000ab82e9d48 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Simon Sprankel <simonsprankel@gmail.com>
Date: Thu, 16 Apr 2015 13:40:28 +0200
Subject: [PATCH] fixed Netresearch_Buergel

---
 .../Netresearch/Scoring/Model/Observer.php         | 11 +++-
 .../Netresearch/Scoring/Model/Service.php          |  2 +-
 .../community/Netresearch/Scoring/etc/config.xml   | 20 +------
 .../frontend/base/default/layout/scoring.xml       | 14 -----
 .../base/default/template/scoring/onepage.phtml    | 69 ----------------------
 5 files changed, 12 insertions(+), 104 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 Netresearch_Buergel/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/scoring.xml
 delete mode 100644 Netresearch_Buergel/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/scoring/onepage.phtml

diff --git a/Netresearch_Buergel/app/code/community/Netresearch/Scoring/Model/Observer.php b/Netresearch_Buergel/app/code/community/Netresearch/Scoring/Model/Observer.php
index b802cd7..3faa646 100644
--- a/Netresearch_Buergel/app/code/community/Netresearch/Scoring/Model/Observer.php
+++ b/Netresearch_Buergel/app/code/community/Netresearch/Scoring/Model/Observer.php
@@ -50,7 +50,8 @@ class Netresearch_Scoring_Model_Observer
             if (false == is_null($solvencyGroup)
                 && false == $solvencyGroup->allowsOrder($event->getQuote())
             ) {
-                throw new Netresearch_Scoring_Model_Validation_Solvency_Exception(
+                $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->setGotoSection('payment');
+                throw new Mage_Payment_Model_Info_Exception(
                     $this->getConfig()->getSolvencyValidationFailedMessage()
                 );
             }
@@ -63,7 +64,8 @@ class Netresearch_Scoring_Model_Observer
             if (false == is_null($addressValidation)
                 && $addressValidation->isFailed()
             ) {
-                throw new Netresearch_Scoring_Model_Validation_Address_Exception(
+                $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->setGotoSection('payment');
+                throw new Mage_Payment_Model_Info_Exception(
                     $addressValidation->getMessage()
                 );
             }
@@ -160,4 +162,9 @@ class Netresearch_Scoring_Model_Observer
             $this->getSession()->unsetAll();
         }
     }
+
+    public function getOnepage()
+    {
+        return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
+    }
 }
diff --git a/Netresearch_Buergel/app/code/community/Netresearch/Scoring/Model/Service.php b/Netresearch_Buergel/app/code/community/Netresearch/Scoring/Model/Service.php
index 3c3015e..98fd95e 100644
--- a/Netresearch_Buergel/app/code/community/Netresearch/Scoring/Model/Service.php
+++ b/Netresearch_Buergel/app/code/community/Netresearch/Scoring/Model/Service.php
@@ -94,7 +94,7 @@ class Netresearch_Scoring_Model_Service extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
             && $customerId = $this->getSession()->getCustomerId()
         ) {
             $log = $this->getLastLogOfCustomer();
-            if ($log && $log->isStillValid()) {
+            if ($log->getId() > 0 && $log->isStillValid()) {
                 $log->increaseCheckoutsAfterThisRequest();
                 $log->save();
                 return $log->getSolvencyGroup();
diff --git a/Netresearch_Buergel/app/code/community/Netresearch/Scoring/etc/config.xml b/Netresearch_Buergel/app/code/community/Netresearch/Scoring/etc/config.xml
index 94ea725..d97884a 100644
--- a/Netresearch_Buergel/app/code/community/Netresearch/Scoring/etc/config.xml
+++ b/Netresearch_Buergel/app/code/community/Netresearch/Scoring/etc/config.xml
@@ -94,15 +94,8 @@
         </translate>
     </adminhtml>
     <frontend>
-        <layout>
-            <updates>
-                <scoring>
-                    <file>scoring.xml</file>
-                </scoring>
-            </updates>
-        </layout>
         <events>
-            <netresearch_scoring_checkout_type_onepage_save_order_before>
+            <sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
                 <observers>
                     <scoring_check_customer_data>
                         <type>singleton</type>
@@ -110,7 +103,7 @@
                         <method>checkCustomerData</method>
                     </scoring_check_customer_data>
                 </observers>
-            </netresearch_scoring_checkout_type_onepage_save_order_before>
+            </sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
             <customer_logout>
                 <observers>
                     <unsetAll>
@@ -136,15 +129,6 @@
                 </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveShipping>
         </events>
-        <routers>
-            <checkout>
-                <args>
-                    <modules>
-                        <Netresearch_Scoring_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Netresearch_Scoring_Checkout</Netresearch_Scoring_Checkout>
-                    </modules>
-                </args>
-            </checkout>
-        </routers>
     </frontend>
     <default>
         <scoring>
diff --git a/Netresearch_Buergel/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/scoring.xml b/Netresearch_Buergel/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/scoring.xml
deleted file mode 100644
index 6e2e1e6..0000000
--- a/Netresearch_Buergel/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/scoring.xml
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,14 +0,0 @@
-<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<!--
- * @category   Scoring
- * @package    Netresearch_Scoring
- * @author     Thomas Kappel <thomas.kappel@netresearch.de>
- * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2011 Netresearch GmbH & Co.KG <http://www.netresearch.de/>
--->
-<layout version="0.1.0">
-    <checkout_onepage_index>
-        <reference name="checkout.onepage">
-            <action method="setTemplate"><template>scoring/onepage.phtml</template></action>
-        </reference>
-    </checkout_onepage_index>
-</layout>
diff --git a/Netresearch_Buergel/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/scoring/onepage.phtml b/Netresearch_Buergel/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/scoring/onepage.phtml
deleted file mode 100644
index 6d9a0f6..0000000
--- a/Netresearch_Buergel/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/scoring/onepage.phtml
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,69 +0,0 @@
-<?php
-/**
- * Magento
- *
- * NOTICE OF LICENSE
- *
- * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
- * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
- * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
- * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
- * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
- * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
- * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
- *
- * DISCLAIMER
- *
- * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
- * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
- * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
- *
- * @category    design
- * @package     base_default
- * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2010 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
- * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
- */
-?>
-<div class="page-title">
-    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></h1>
-</div>
-<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('varien/accordion.js') ?>"></script>
-<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/scoring.js') ?>"></script>
-<script type="text/javascript">countryRegions = <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?></script>
-<ol class="opc" id="checkoutSteps">
-<?php $i=0; foreach($this->getSteps() as $_stepId => $_stepInfo): ?>
-<?php if (!$this->getChild($_stepId) || !$this->getChild($_stepId)->isShow()): continue; endif; $i++ ?>
-    <li id="opc-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="section<?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['allow'])?' allow':'' ?><?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['complete'])?' saved':'' ?>">
-        <div class="step-title">
-            <span class="number"><?php echo $i ?></span>
-            <h2><?php echo $_stepInfo['label'] ?></h2>
-            <a href="#"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
-        </div>
-        <div id="checkout-step-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">
-            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_stepId) ?>
-        </div>
-    </li>
-<?php endforeach ?>
-</ol>
-<script type="text/javascript">
-//<![CDATA[
-    var accordion = new Accordion('checkoutSteps', '.step-title', true);
-    <?php if($this->getActiveStep()): ?>
-    accordion.openSection('opc-<?php echo $this->getActiveStep() ?>');
-    <?php endif ?>
-    var checkout = new Checkout(accordion,{
-        progress: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/progress') ?>',
-        review: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/review') ?>',
-        saveMethod: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveMethod') ?>',
-        failure: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>'}
-    );
-    var paymentCssSelector = '<?php
-        $version = explode(".", Mage::getVersion());
-        if($version[0]==1 && $version[1]<8){
-            echo '#checkout-payment-method-load dl dt';
-        }elseif ($version[0]==1 && $version[1]>=8) {
-            echo '#checkout-payment-method-load dt';
-        }
-    ?>';
-//]]>
-</script>
-- 
1.9.1
```